# How do I return chart data to the chart?

Tags: angularjs, fusioncharts

I'm building a dashboard using AngularJS and ASp.Net MVC. I'm new to Angular and what I would like to do is to display list of charts on the website. each chart have Id and if that Id is passed to Asp.Net controller via GetChartData() it will returns Json data for the chart. This works without any problems.

Now I'm having a problem when trying to iterate myListOfCharts. The title "Chart number n" is displayed for each chart and the chart object as well but without the data.
I think the issue is with this code but cannot figure out what:

```
.success(function (data) {
                    return data;
                })
```

My app.js file:

```
(function() {
     var app = angular.module('aDashboard', ["ng-fusioncharts"]);
app.controller('fussionController', function ($scope, ChartService) {

    $scope.myListOfCharts = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

    getChartData();
    function getChartData(chartId) {
        ChartService.getChartData(chartId)
            .success(function (data) {
                return data;
            })
            .error(function (error) {
                alert($scope.status)
            });
    }
});

app.factory('ChartService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var ChartService = {};
    ChartService.getChartData = function (chartId) {
        return $http.get('/FusionCharts/GetChartData/', { params: { chartID: chartId } });
    };
    return ChartService;
}]);

})();
```

My html file:

```
<div ng-controller="fussionController">
    <div ng-repeat="n in myListOfCharts">
        <h2>Chart number {{n}}</h2>
        <fusioncharts width="100%"
                      height="400"
                      type="MSCombi2D"
                      datasource="{{getChartData(n)}}"></fusioncharts>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**
Thanks hawk-i-, your answer with slightly modification works:
app.js file:

```
app.controller('fussionController', function ($scope, ChartService) {

    $scope.myListOfCharts = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

    $scope.chartData = [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}];

    $scope.getChartData = function (chartId) {
        ChartService.getChartData(chartId)
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.chartData[chartId] = data;
            })
            .error(function (error) {
                alert($scope.status)
            });
    };
});
```

And my html file:

```
<div ng-controller="fussionController">
        <div ng-repeat="n in myListOfCharts" ng-init="getChartData(n)">
            <h2>Chart number {{n}}</h2>
            <fusioncharts width="100%"
                          height="400"
                          type="MSCombi2D"
                          datasource="{{chartData[n]}}"></fusioncharts>
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" ng-click="getChartData(n)">Click me to change data</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But this isn't very elegant solution, as if I will have a chart with an ID of 35 or 155, I would have to create large array with most of the elements empty. 
Any idea how to improve this code?

Comment: Remove this line `getChartData();` from your app.js
Other than that are there any errors in the console?

Comment: No, no errors in the console when I remove getChartData(); but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that you are binding your datasource to a function call getChartData(), this is not observing value change.

bind it to a property:

```
(function() {
     var app = angular.module('aDashboard', ["ng-fusioncharts"]);
app.controller('fussionController', function ($scope, ChartService) {

    $scope.myListOfCharts = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
    var chartData = [];

    $scope.getChartData = function(chartId) {
        ChartService.getChartData(chartId)
            .success(function (data) {
                chartData[chartId] = data;
            })
            .error(function (error) {
                alert($scope.status)
            });
    }
});

app.factory('ChartService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var ChartService = {};
    ChartService.getChartData = function (chartId) {
        return $http.get('/FusionCharts/GetChartData/', { params: { chartID: chartId } });
    };
    return ChartService;
}]);

})();
```

and in your html, call getChartData in ng-init like:

```
<div ng-controller="fussionController">
    <div ng-repeat="n in myListOfCharts" ng-init="$scope.getChartData(n)">
        <h2>Chart number {{n}}</h2>
        <fusioncharts width="100%"
                      height="400"
                      type="MSCombi2D"
                      datasource="{{chartData[n]}}"></fusioncharts>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

if you treat your ids as strings ie. ['1', '2', '3',...] and var charData = {}; then your chart data array will be associative array and you wont have a initialization issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is almost what I expect, question edited.

Comment: you don't have to make your ids string, just convert them to string when using chartData

Comment: I have try that this afternoon, and it returns the charts data and place them in the chart datasource but the chart doesn't display. Interesting is that if I copy the stringified version of chartData and paste as the value of chartData it works.

Comment: that may have something to do with digest loop. I added highcharts in my application in similar way

Answer (score 1):

Check https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng

**Here is one example:**

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["highcharts-ng"]);

myapp.controller('myctrl', function ($scope) {

$scope.addPoints = function () {
    var seriesArray = $scope.highchartsNG.series
    var rndIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * seriesArray.length);
    seriesArray[rndIdx].data = seriesArray[rndIdx].data.concat([1, 10, 20])
};

$scope.addSeries = function () {
    var rnd = []
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        rnd.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1)
    }
    $scope.highchartsNG.series.push({
        data: rnd
    })
}

$scope.removeRandomSeries = function () {
    var seriesArray = $scope.highchartsNG.series
    var rndIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * seriesArray.length);
    seriesArray.splice(rndIdx, 1)
}

$scope.options = {
    type: 'line'
}

$scope.swapChartType = function () {
    if (this.highchartsNG.options.chart.type === 'line') {
        this.highchartsNG.options.chart.type = 'bar'
    } else {
        this.highchartsNG.options.chart.type = 'line'
    }
}

$scope.highchartsNG = {
    options: {
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [10, 15, 12, 8, 7]
    }],
    title: {
        text: 'Hello'
    },
    loading: false
}

});
```

jsFiddle Example
http://jsfiddle.net/pablojim/cp73s/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm looking for help with Fusion Charts and not Highcharts, however I didn't decide which charting I will so your answer maybe helpful in the future.